# Basic arithmetic in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I add two numbers in tikz?
Multiplication seems simple enough...

I want to "stagger" the nodes in the following figure, so they nodes in one layer are inbetween the nodes of the layer below instead of directly on top of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\def\layersep{1.5cm}
\def\unitsep{1.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,draw,fill=white!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
    \path   node[neuron] (L_2_\x) at (\x*\unitsep,2*\layersep){};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,2}
    \path   node[neuron] (L_3_\x) at (\x*\unitsep,3*\layersep){};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,1}
    \path   node[neuron] (L_4_\x) at (\x*\unitsep,4*\layersep){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried these, but they don't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}


\def\layersep{1.5cm}
\def\unitsep{1.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,draw,fill=white!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
    \path   node[neuron] (L_2_\x) at (\x*\unitsep,2*\layersep){};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,2}
    \path   node[neuron] (L_3_\x) at ({.5+\x}*\unitsep,3*\layersep){};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,1}
    \path   node[neuron] (L_4_\x) at ($1+\x$*\unitsep,4*\layersep){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so it compiles!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this?

[image: layered neurons]

Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated and ought not be used.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\layersep{1.5cm}
\def\unitsep{1.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    shorten >=1pt,->,
    draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    neuron/.style={circle,draw,fill=white!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt}
  ]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
  \path   node[neuron] (L_2_\x) at (\x*\unitsep,2*\layersep){};
  \foreach \x in {1,...,2}
  \path   node[neuron] (L_3_\x) at ({(.5+\x)*\unitsep},3*\layersep){};
  \foreach \x in {1,...,1}
  \path   node[neuron] (L_4_\x) at ({(1+\x)*\unitsep},4*\layersep){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In fact `calc` isn't needed here. `calc` is needed when you want to do arithmetic with *coordinates* e.g. 'add' point `(a)` to point `(b)`. If you are doing arithmetic *within* coordinates but with *numbers*, it plays no role. And you only want dollar signs when *either* using `calc` to do arithmetic with coordinates or *typesetting* maths, as opposed to doing it. So the dollars here are causing trouble and had to go.

Then remember that `()` represents a sub-calculation, if you like. At least, maybe that's not the official way to explain it, but it is how I think of it. So if we want to add `x` to `y` and multiply by `z`, then we want to do the addition first `x+y` and to group it, use `(x+y)` and multiply by `z`, `(x+y)*z`. But, in a coordinate specification, this will confuse TikZ as it doesn't expect a `(` here. So we need to protect the calculation `{(x+y)*z}` within the coordinate specification.

Note that my terminology here doubtless leaves much to be desired - I am not using the technically correct terms. (I said 'protect' but not in the `\protect` sense....) But maybe it helps a bit to think of how things get nested here.