# Tikz \def arithmetic division

Tags: tikz-pgf, variable, arithmetic

This is, I hope, a trivial question, but one that has cost me a lot of time. I am drawing a simple `TikZ` picture. I define some variables which specify the `coordinates` of the lines, `nodes` and so on.

```
\def \Xa {4};
and then I can do
\def \Wdth {6};
\def \Xb (\Xa+\Wdth};
```

but the following does not work, it runs but uses the wrong value.

```
\def \Xmid {\Xa+\Wdth/2};
```

A second question is why can I not use variable names such as `\X1` rather then `\Xa`

Comment: Please, give an MWE, read : [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: See the explanation by @cfr at -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286589/197451 ---- you need to do the subcalculation first with `( )` and protect it from outside with `{ }`  -- note your first calculation shows `(\Xa+\Wdth}` -- something seems to be missing

Comment: It is a general rule of TeX that you can only use alphabets in your control word. `\Xa` is considered as a single control word, while `\X1` is considered as a control word `\X` followed by a number `1`. If you really want to make an exception about this you need to learn carefully of catergory codes, or to use the lengthy version of control sequences: `\csname ... \endcsname`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do it is difficult to say but I suspect that you are going about this the wrong way. If you want an easy way to access or reuse coordinates in  [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) then you should use named nodes or coordinates:

```
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (2,3);
\draw (O)--(A);
\node (B) at (3,2){B here};
\draw(A)--(B);
```

If you want to set widths etc for nodes, or any [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) object, then `\tikzset` is your friend:

```
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style = {
     draw = blue,
     fill = yellow!10,
     minimum width = 20mm
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode] at (3,3){stuff}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Importantly, you can have parameters inside `\tikzset` and you can also define `pics`, which are a very powerful way of reusing tikz code.

Finally, if you do really want to do calculations with variables like this then for integer calculations you can use:

```
\numexpr\Xa+\Wdth\relax
```

and for non-integer calculations

```
 \pgfmathparse{\Xa+\Wdth/2}\pgfmathresult
```

or, if you need to save the result in a macro,

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\Xmid{\Xa+\Wdth/2}
```

Of course, you can use `\pgfmathparse` for integer calculations too but  if you want an honest integer then it is advisable to declare this explicitly:

```
\pgfmathparse{int(\Xa+\Xb)}\pgfmathresult
```